# Want to exclude specific records from number of xml files using bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have a large set of XML files contains order records. I want to extract all the order records if they are matching "Completed" in the order records to new output file
For example -

```
<Order> 
     <ID>..</Id>
     <Date>..</Date>
     <Status>Completed<Status>
</Order>
```

see above example, I want to extract the entire order details which are matching above condition.

Comment: Do you have to use bash for this task? I highly recommend to use a parser in your preferred language.  It'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, particularly [ask]. We're glad to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Good luck.

Comment: Hi jgmh,

I was using the following command to see what's coming up with grep, but it does not show me exact what I am looking .
    grep "<OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>" order-*.XML | sed -n '/<Order>/,/<\/Order>/p' > completed.xml

Comment: Please edit your additional information into the question, instead of hiding it inside a comment. Please show sample input and the output your attempt produced and explain what did not satisfy you. I.e. please make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -A 4 '<Order>' xml_files | grep -B 3 -A 1 '<Status>Completed<Status>'
```

Replace 'xml_files' above with all the xml files. You can use globbing (*) to get multiple files if they are similarly named.